# What is wrong with this Database connection string?

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I am trying to connect to my remote MySQL server, using the following code.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong as the replacement of database connection info with variables doesn't seem to be working.

```
   using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;       

   string db_Server = "10.0.0.0";
   string db_Name   = "myDatabase";
   string db_User   = "myUser";
   string db_Pass   = "myPassword";


   // Connection String
   MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("server = {0}; database = {1}; uid = {2}; pwd = {3}", db_server, db_Name, db_User, db_Pass);
```

As a PHP developer, I prefer to use the code above instead of the deliberate casting below:

```
   MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("server=10.0.0.0; database=myDatabase; uid=myUser; pwd=myPassword");
```

But as you can see in this image, I am getting a lot of red squiggles:  http://screencast.com/t/xlwoG9by

Comment: `db_Server, db_Name, db_User, db_Pass` not `db_Server, db_User, db_Pass, db_Name`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Order of your parameter is wrong, it should be:

```
db_server, db_Name, db_User, db_Pass
```

Currently it is:

```
"server = {0}; database = {1}; uid = {2};   pwd = {3}"
       db_Server         db_User   db_Pass   db_Name
```

So your statement should be:

```
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(string.Format(
"server = {0}; database = {1}; uid = {2}; pwd = {3}", 
db_Server,db_Name, db_User, db_Pass));
```

**EDIT:** based on the comments and discussion, the error you are getting is that you are trying all the stuff at class level. You should have these lines inside a method and call that method where you need it. Something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    string db_Server = "10.0.0.0";
    string db_User = "myUser";
    string db_Pass = "myPassword";
    string db_Name = "myDatabase";


    public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(string.Format(
                   "server = {0}; database = {1}; uid = {2}; pwd = {3}",
                    db_Server, db_Name, db_User, db_Pass));
        return myConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need a port too, after server.

Comment: Remember to include string.Format

Comment: @Jeagr, have you included String.Format ? you are missing that

Comment: @Jeagr, check the statement I have written in my answer, you are missing `string.Format(.....)`, copy paste the code I have in my answer for myConnection and let me know if the error still stays

Comment: @Jeagr, you are formatting string using place holders, you have to use string.Format as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21371/discussion-between-jeagr-and-habib)

Answer (score 1):

```
 MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(string.Format("server = {0}; database = {1}; uid = {2}; pwd = {3}", db_Server, db_User, db_Pass, db_Name))
```

string.Format() is missing

Comment: With string.Format the other issue is wrong parameter, you need to adjust that

Comment: True. Missed that. But basically the red squiggles occur because of the missing string.Format() ;)